# Keyup event fires action of next input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 input boxes. I want to call function to highlight box when users enters any value in that. By using keyup function I am able to achieve it but it also fires keyup function of its next input element. Below is my code

Working demo - 
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G38SF7O5Q7MQ

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="cDate" />
    <input type="text" class="cMonth" />
    <input type="text" class="cYear" />
</div>
<div class="error-msg"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.cDate').on('keyup blur change', function(){
            $(this).next().trigger('focus');
            highlightInputs(this)
      });

      $('.cMonth').on('keyup blur change', function(){
            $(this).next().trigger('focus');
            highlightInputs(this)
      });

      $('.cYear').on('keyup blur change', function(){
            $(this).trigger('focusout');
            highlightInputs(this)
      });
    });

    function highlightInputs(_inputs) {
        $(_inputs).each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == ''){
              $(this).addClass('error');
              $('.error-msg').text('Please enter valid date');
              $('.error-msg').show();
            }
            else{
              $(this).removeClass('error');
              $('.error-msg').text('Please enter valid date');
              $('.error-msg').hide();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I just copied your code into a snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cDate').on('keyup blur change', function() {
    $(this).next().trigger('focus');
    highlightInputs(this)
  });

  $('.cMonth').on('keyup blur change', function() {
    $(this).next().trigger('focus');
    highlightInputs(this)
  });

  $('.cYear').on('keyup blur change', function() {
    $(this).trigger('focusout');
    highlightInputs(this)
  });

  $("input").on('keydown', function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (code == 9) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  });
});

function highlightInputs(_inputs) {
  $(_inputs).each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      $(this).addClass('error');
      $('.error-msg').text('Please enter valid date');
      $('.error-msg').show();
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('error');
      $('.error-msg').text('Please enter valid date');
      $('.error-msg').hide();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="text" class="cDate" />
  <input type="text" class="cMonth" />
  <input type="text" class="cYear" />
</div>
<div class="error-msg"></div>
```

Comment: see this link https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G38SF7O5Q7MQ . Just put any number in input field 1. Then press Tab key. It will fire event for field 2 which is fine but it will fire same for field 3 as well

Comment: It's because the tab key fires on keydown, and then your JS code fires on keyup after the tab has already fired!

Comment: This will disable tab key functionality. I don’t want users to loose tab functionality